# AngularJS set title and description in head when populating content from JSON

Tags: angularjs

Before I go and do this in Jquery out of frustration I figured I would ask what the angular way is?

I'm building an AngularJS site using a model based of the Phonecat tutorial example on the AngularJS site.

I found this [method](https://coderwall.com/p/vcfo4q) to set the title of a page and can work out how to modify it to do description as well in the app config but this doesn't work when I'm populating pages with content via json. I tried doing it using a ngbind method as well but have yet to find a working solution as I think something to do with the order in which files are loaded is breaking.

For example

```
when('/faq', {
    templateUrl: 'sub_pages/articles.html',
    title: 'Landing page title goes here, not to big a deal'
  }).
  when('/things-to-do/:activityID', {
    templateUrl: 'sub_pages/activity-detail.html',
    controller: 'activityDetailCtrl',
    title: 'If I put a title here it will be the same on all of these pieces of content'
  }).
```

What method can I use in order to set title on both the landing pages and also the pages which draw their content from a JSON feed?

EDIT - ANSWER BELOW

Comment: Please provide a plunkr based on your not working solution, so that we can work on it.

Comment: With the number of dependencies involved will plunkr even handle that?

Comment: I see only `ng-route` as a dep. What else?

Comment: controllers, directives, services none of which have anything wrong with them.

Comment: you don't need to import all you project into a Plunker. You just need to implement a basic 2 pages app with the routing you're using to showcase your problem.

Comment: That's not likely to illustrate the problem as it's far more complex than a two page app. Basically I'm trying to implement the phonecat example on the Angular site but need to be able to populate header title and description tags from both static landing page templates and  dynamically populated templates that draw their content from json feeds. 

I don't need to debug the code the code works, what I need is a method to populate tags inside my header from a controller that may need to draw content from other controllers.

Comment: If you can populate the header title in a 2 pages example, it seems fair that you will be able to do it on the real use case too...

Answer (score 0):

After about 2 days of bashing my head against a wall trying to work this one out it's actually quite simple and works for both static pages and templates with dynamically loaded content.

Inside the view pages (html that loads inside of ng-view) add a couple of divs (you can put this anywhere really) and then inside them you need to load in ng-init.

ng-init="$root.title = path.to.title"
ng-init="$root.description = path.to.description"
This will set the title and description on the root scope. The "path.to." is just an example path to content in json, you can replace this with plain text as well which is how I deal with landing pages.

Then on the index.html or what ever page your app is based on inside the head you just need to load in.

Your Page Title

This will automatically set your page title and description meta tags and you can pretty much use this formula for any other meta data you need to create.

I haven't tested this yet with Prerender.io or any other cache service but will do some checks and post the results here.

Answer (score -1):

Something like 
$document[0].title = "xyz";